# Socket hang up, exactly after 1 minute. Formidable library

Tags: node.js, sockets, upload, strapi, formidable

I am trying to upload a 500mb video on Strapi CMS. The software is using formidable to upload the files. When I try to upload a file that could be uploaded under 1 minute, there are no error and the file gets uploaded successfully. But if a file takes longer than a minute to upload I get `ECONNRESET` error on postman and the following error on the server logs

```
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/cms/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:122:19)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:314:20)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:535:9)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:528:3)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03:     at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
0|cms  | 2021-10-04T06:28:03: [2021-10-04T06:28:03.363Z] debug POST /upload (60004 ms) 500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own server and up the max duration and max size for http requests.

Comment: I think you are right. Meanwhile when I was trying to solve this, I used nginx and configured a reverse proxy to my cms application and it started working. But I did not set any timeout or anything, the basic configuration worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the default configuration is pretty generous nowadays